# The word that describes the things you do as a person

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I know that there is a term for the things someone does. 
Little things, like the way you fold your arms or the filler words you use in your sentences.

I would like to know what the word is if anyone knows what I mean.

Comment: Mode of behavior, way of behaving(in general). Habit (or manner) of folding arms (in particular).

Answer (score 12):

“Idiosyncrasy” is a great word for referring to the unique things a person does, while “mannerism” might suit certain uses better as a more general term:

> **mannerism**
>
> noun
>
> 1. a habitual gesture or way of speaking or behaving; an idiosyncrasy.
>
> <sub>Source: [Definition of “mannerism” in Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/mannerism)</sub>

For instance, I might say “[my pet] Aki has an **idiosyncrasy** where he's prone to running in circles when it's snowing at night.”[¹](http://www.chickensmoothie.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=2098306&start=10) That is a specific behavior that is unique to that particular individual.

Conversely, I could say “David Cameron has adopted all the **mannerisms** of Tony Blair, including using his hands a lot to show he's sincere.”[²](https://twitter.com/stirringtrouble/status/537224562170413056) Many people gesticulate or use their hands while talking, and some patterns resemble one another, so this is not an *idiosyncracy* of Cameron or Blair, but a common *mannerism* that they purportedly share.

Answer (score 3):

The closest match that comes to my mind is *idiosyncrasy*.

> [idiosyncrasy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/idiosyncrasy) (plural *idiosyncrasies*)
>
> 1: A mode of behavior or way of thought peculiar to an individual
>
> *one of his little **idiosyncrasies** was always preferring to be in the car first*
>
> 1.1: A distinctive or peculiar feature or characteristic of a place or thing:
>
> *the **idiosyncrasies** of the prison system*

Answer (score 0):

There are a few words that mean that.
The first ones that come to mind are "habit" and "tendency."

Go on dictionary.com and check whether they are what you are looking for.
If not, clarify your meaning further and I will see what other words will work.
Hope this helps,
Pyraminx

Answer (score -1):

Personal.

Sometimes, the answer is very simply, very obvious—so obvious and so simple, that someone immersed in too many complexities forgets that simple exists.

Comment: Can you use this word in a sentence in a way that makes it fit the request?